# Directive with same template but with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML :

```
<div custDirective id="managerNames"></div>
<div custDirective id="empNames"></div>
```

Template.html

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
<ol><li>{{name}}</li></ol>
</div>
```

Directive link function :

```
if(attr.id === "name"){
scope.names = ["A","B","C","D"];
}else{
scope.names = ["E","F","G","H"];
}
```

I want to get the dynamic list based on the id attribute.i.e, If id is managerNames then my ng-repeat should repeat a,b,c,d else it should repeat e,f,g,h.

How to achieve this? I am using angular.js 1.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

you can send an attribute to your link where it will check on the value you send to it and work accordingly to it

Here is an example :

```
//Directive 

angular.module('yourModule').directive('directiveName',

      function($parse) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: "your/template.html",
          scope: {
            check: '@',
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             if(scope.check == "whatever"){

             }

          }
     })



//HTML

      <directive-name check="whatever"></directive-name>
```

Comment: even after checking like this. If i am changing the scope variable ultimaltely the names collection is changing. i dont want like that. In my page i need to use the same directive but it should render different collections.